# Force kubernetes ingress cname format

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

With Kubernetes, in a multi-tenant env., controlled by RBAC, when creating a new Ingress cname, I would like to force cname format like:

`${service}.${namespace}.${cluster}.kube.infra`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${servce}
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ${service}.${namespace}.${cluster}.kube.infra
      secretName: conso-elasticsearch-ssl
  rules:
    - host: ${service}.${namespace}.${cluster}.kube.infra
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: ${service}
              servicePort: 9200
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by it by writing a [validating admission webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook) which validates the ingress yaml and rejects it if the cname format is not as per the way you want. A better way to is to use Open Policy agent(OPA) and write [rego policy](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/). [Here](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-tutorial/) is a guide on how to perform policy driven validation of ingress using OPA.

```
package kubernetes.admission

import data.kubernetes.namespaces

operations = {"CREATE", "UPDATE"}

deny[msg] {
    input.request.kind.kind == "Ingress"
    operations[input.request.operation]
    host := input.request.object.spec.rules[_].host
    not fqdn_matches_any(host, valid_ingress_hosts)
    msg := sprintf("invalid ingress host %q", [host])
}

valid_ingress_hosts = {
    // valid hosts
}

fqdn_matches_any(str, patterns) {
    fqdn_matches(str, patterns[_])
}

fqdn_matches(str, pattern) {
    // validation logic
}

fqdn_matches(str, pattern) {
    not contains(pattern, "*")
    str == pattern
}
```

Comment: Woa, didnt know about OPA, it sounds magic! thanks you.